# How to achieve this low poly lighting?

Tags: rendering, texturing, materials, lighting

Ok, new to 3D lighting overall here and Ive gone through every Blender lighting tutorial for low poly like PigArt, etc but can't achieve this lighting/rendering - low poly so that the triangles are defined but more glossy:

https://dribbble.com/shots/3471048-Xbox-clubs-image

OR [image]

These are different from just a basic sun light, the world set to white color and everything that is described in tutorials. Ive tried setting materials to glossy but still can't get this.

How can I do this? Any good tutorials?

Comment: Cycles or Blender Internal?

Comment: cycles renderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image: final]

I've looked at the other works from Alex Pushilin and here is my attempt to reproduce it.

Setup is very simple. One **Sun Lamp** with warm color and small **Size** and **RGB Background** (this one is with **Spherical Gradient**).

For materials I've used **Principled Shader** with **Roughness - 1.0**.

Most important thing here is to use **Filimic Color management**. I've used **Look > High Contrast** with a little correction from **RGB Curves**.

Also I've lower a bit **Saturation** in **Compositing**.

Every probably will need a little bit different settings.

[image: setup]